# How can I create and validate webhooks for onedrive or sharepoint online?

Tags: java, azure, webhooks, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I want a subscription to my OneDrive folder. After a successful authorization and receiving the access token for my OneDrive, I can work with all of my folders and files in OneDrive. But I fail to create a subscription.

I am implementing a Java Spring Boot Application which is already deployed to Azure and is available by e.g. ***https://{tenant}.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api***

> When I try to create a subscription, I receive a response code: 400 with the message: "Validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request."

After reading all of the wonderful [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/subscription_post_subscriptions?view=odsp-graph-online), I could not find a solution for my problem. Maybe I misunderstood some general setup things.

These are my endpoint's:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class OneDriveSubscriptionsController {

    @Autowired
    private SubscriptionService subscriptionService;

    // Should be used to create a subscription
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create() {

        OneDriveSubscriptionVO subscription = new OneDriveSubscriptionVO();
        oneDriveSubscriptionService.createSubscription(subscription);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Should be used to validate a subscription
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> validation(@RequestParam String validationtoken) {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(validationtoken, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }

    // Should be used to receive notification's.
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/notification" consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> subscriptionUpdate(@RequestBody OneDriveSubscriptionVO subscription) {
        // working with received notifications.
    }
}
```

My service class:

```java
@Service
public class SubscriptionService {

    public synchronized String create(OneDriveSubscriptionVO subscription) {
        String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions";
        String authorization = "Bearer "+AccessInformation.getAccess_token();
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String ret = null;

            try {
                URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url);
                URI uri = builder.build();

                String serialisedJsonString = Util.serializeJson(subscription); 
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(serialisedJsonString);

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
                request.setEntity(entity);
                request.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

                ret = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

My helper class:

```java
public class Util {
    private <T>String serializeJson(T obj) {
        Gson gson;
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
        builder.setPrettyPrinting(); 
        gson = builder.create(); 
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

My OneDriveSubscriptionVO class (simplified):

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OneDriveSubscriptionVO {

    private String id;
    private String clientState;
    private String expirationDateTime;
    private String notificationUrl;
    private String resource;
    private String changeType;

    public OneDriveSubscriptionVO() {
        this.clientState = "random string";
        this.expirationDateTime = "2019-05-15T11:23:00.000Z";
        this.notificationUrl= "https://{tenant}.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/notification";
        this.resource = "/me/drive/root";
        this.changeType = "updated";
    }
```

So far as i know, I have to create a subscription with the data from my OneDriveSubscriptionVO Constructor. Within 5 seconds I have to response with the received validationtoken.

After sending the creation data i receive the error "Validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request." and no validationtoken to enable the subscription.

This is the json which I want to use to create the subschription:

```json
{
  "clientState": "random string",
  "expirationDateTime": "2019-05-15T11:23:00.000Z",
  "notificationUrl": "https://{tenant}.cloudapp.azure.com/onedrive/api/notification",
  "resource": "/me/drive/root",
  "changeType": "updated"
}
```

This is what I receive:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5bf8a5e2-efd4-4863-bdc3-1fb7c89afa83",
      "date": "2019-04-16T11:43:58"
    }
  }
}
```

I think something is generally wrong, because no endpoint are triggered after my "create subscription POST Request".

Answer (score 0):

The validation request is sent to the same endpoint as the notifications. It looks like you're expecting the validation to be done against `/create` while the endpoint you specify for the notifications is `/notification`. You'll want to merge implementation of POST-to-/create with POST-to-/notification. Here's a sample Azure Function that will give you an idea what this looks like:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
 
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
 
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage request, TraceWriter log)
{
    var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var query = request.RequestUri.Query
        .TrimStart('?')
        .Split('&')
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => Uri.UnescapeDataString(x[1]).Replace("+", " "), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ?? new Dictionary<string,string>();

    string token;

    if (query.TryGetValue("validationToken", out token))
    {
        var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token)));
        return response;
    }
 
    return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done!");
}
```

Comment: Please note that I have received mostly `validationToken` as query argument, but also `ValidationToken` and once `validationtoken`; if `query.TryGetValue` does case-significant string comparisons, you might have inexplicable failures now and then.